# Which iOS devices are multi core?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I think iPad 2 and above are. What about iPhones?
Is it for iPhone 4S and above or does the iPhone 4 has multi core built in as well?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you think this actually matters, relevant to programming iOS apps?

Comment: I am diving deep in to GCD and read about how in multi core devices it can run threads on multiple cores. I wrote this question after reading that "With the introduction of multicore devices such as the new iPad, programmers can write amazing multicore-aware multithreaded apps for iOS." in the iOS7 programming cookbook. I find my question relevant curiosity of a curious and always willing to learn developer and really not sure what the down votes and patronising is about.

Comment: Single-core processors can run multiple threads.  Every iOS app runs multiple threads.

Comment: Sure it is. You can write multi threads applications for one CPU using scheduling algorithms. However it is different than writing "amazing **multicore-aware** multithreaded apps for iOS"!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those that have A5 processor or above. (iPad 2 and above, iPhone 4S and above, iPod Touch (Generation 5 and above). Why?

Comment: Thanks. Please see comments to my question for why :)